# WM_COPYDATA, PostThreadMessage, and Error 1159

Tags: winapi

I am trying to send data from one app to another using WM_COPYDATA. Both apps are console and have no window. I can send user messages just fine. When I try to send WM_COPYDATA, and setup the data structure or not, I get error 1159, which basically says I have to send using a synchronous message call... yet there is no SendThreadMessage.

It seems this is a oversight in the api or docs?  There seems to be no way to use WM_COPYDATA using only threads without windows?

Comment: Please show your send and receive code, including message loop.

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` requires a window since it can't be sent asynchronously.

Comment: Another common means of inter-process communication are [pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780.aspx) (or [named pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590.aspx)). This might be more appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: @IInspectable yeah, but I was looking for something very simple to setup.  Since one can't send large amounts of data I have decided to send bytes at a time in the WPARAM and LPARAM as the data. Not as performant but I'm only using this to debug things.

Comment: If simple to set up and **use** are your goals, go with pipes. Created in message mode, they ensure atomicity of sent data. You don't have to implement your own protocol on top of the transport, to know, when a message is complete. And they are asynchronous, so that the sender doesn't have to wait for the receiver to read the data (as is the case with `SendMessage`).

Answer (score 5):

`WM_COPYDATA` can only be sent and cannot be posted. Because the payload is marshaled between processes, temporary data structures are created to support that marshaling. They need to be destroyed when the message processing is complete. That implies that the message must be delivered synchronously.

All of this means that you cannot use `PostThreadMessage`. Instead you will need to create a window to act as the recipient of such messages. Note that this window can be a [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) and does not need to be visible.

Comment: Well, I can then just stream the data using PostThreadMessage. Seems to be the easiest way. I don't need performance, Just transfer.